# Proper way to generate table rows in php

Tags: wordpress, html-table

I am trying to generate a table with rows but the way I am doing it seems wrong, it just creates a table for each item.

```
if ($favorite_post_ids):
        $favorite_post_ids = array_reverse($favorite_post_ids);
        foreach ($favorite_post_ids as $post_id) {
            $p = get_post($post_id);
            echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"5\">\n"; 
            echo "<tr>\n"; 
            echo "<td>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array(55,55), array('class' => 'fav-thumbs')) . "</td>\n"; 
            echo "<td><a href='".get_permalink($post_id)."' title='". $p->post_title ."'><span class='fav-title'>" . $p->post_title . "</span></a></td>\n"; 
            echo "<td>";
            wpfp_remove_favorite_link($post_id);
            echo "</td>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n"; 
            echo "</table>\n";
```

Little help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"5\">\n";` //this needs to only happen once before foreach.

`echo "</table>\n";` //this needs to happen only once at the end.

And you want to use $html variable of some sort if you want the page to load faster. (As long as your not trying to generate a large table.)